# When creating two instances of the same fragment and registering them only the second one created gets event

Tags: android, fragment

I have created two fragments in a `ViewPager` , when I click on first one , Second fragment is taking the click.

This issue puts me in another position, when I create two instance from same fragment but with different data.

```
{

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int index) {

        switch (index) {
        case 1:
                return FragmentBrandList.getInstance(tabs.getBrandList2(), 19,
                        title);
        case 0:
            return FragmentBrandList.getInstance(tabs.getBrandList1(), 19,
                        title);
        }
        return null;

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }
}
```

After creating `ViewPager` , both the fragments get created correctly , but when I click on any thing in the first fragment , the click event gets fired in second fragment not in the first fragment.

EDIT

```
public class TabsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    public TabsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }
    @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int index) {

            switch (index) {
            case 1:
                    return FragmentBrandList.getInstance(tabs.getBrandList2(), 19,
                            title);
            case 0:
                return FragmentBrandList.getInstance(tabs.getBrandList1(), 19,
                            title);
            }
            return null;

        }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return 2;
    }



in FragmentBrandList

public class FragmentBrandList extends Fragment {

    ArrayList<Brand> brandList = new ArrayList<Brand>();
    int discoverID;
    RecyclerView listView;
    LinearLayoutManager mLayoutManager;

    public static FragmentBrandList getInstance(ArrayList<Brand> brandList,
            int discoverID, String title) {

        FragmentBrandList frag = new FragmentBrandList();
        Bundle b = new Bundle();
        b.putSerializable("brandList", brandList);
        b.putInt("discoverID", discoverID);
        b.putString("title", title);
        frag.setArguments(b);
        return frag;

    }

    public FragmentBrandList() {

    }

    String title = "";
    View v;
    boolean isInflated = false;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        if (v == null) {

            v = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_list_view_brownbg,
                    container, false);
            isInflated = true;
        } else {

            isInflated = false;
            ((ViewGroup) v.getParent()).removeView(v);

        }
        return v;
    }

    MainActivity activity;

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
        if (isInflated) {
            activity = (MainActivity) getActivity();

            initView();

        }
    }
public void initView(){
title = getArguments().getString("title");
        discoverID = getArguments().getInt("discoverID");

        listView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.listView);
        mLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());

        listView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
        listView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        listView.setLayoutManager(mLayoutManager);

        listView.setAdapter(new BrandListRecAdapter(getActivity(),
                R.layout.single_item_listview, brandList));



}
@Override
    public void onResume() {
// handle on click

((BrandListRecAdapter) listView.getAdapter())
                .setOnItemClickListener(new ItemClickListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onItemClickListener(final int pos, View v) {

                            activity.replaceCurrentFragment(
                                    FragmentBrandDetails.getInstance(
                                            brandList.get(pos), "bank"), true,
                                    true);
}}
```

EDIT

i think problem cause 
when create second fragment , listview.onclick is overwrite first one !!
how can solve this peb?

EDIT 
thank you to every one try to help me 
problem is already because i use same adapter and same fragment 
when second fragment created it is overwrite on item click 
so when click in item is called second one !!!

Comment: Please post any relevant code.

Comment: Are your fragments coming on top of each other? If they are, then making the root element clickable should solve it.

Comment: how cane make fragment coming on top of each other ? please in details , or put example

Comment: My guess is you're accidentally overwriting your listeners.

Comment: Are you using any singleton instance when calling ragmentBrandList.getInstance(tabs.getBrandList1(), 19,
                        title)

Comment: FragmentBrandList is same class , but i send differ data , this data is already reach to fragment coreclty,and create with this data listview , but when click any item in list view , this event call in second fragment created !!

Answer (score 0):

Just put this android:clickable="true" in every fragment layout, and this will not happen again.

Comment: Make sure that should be in the root of the layout

Answer (score 0):

This is just an educated guess, but because a `ViewPager` will always create at least one extra `Fragment` on either side of the currently visible fragment, you may be creating two virtually identical `Fragments` in parallel, assigning them both `onItemClickListeners` in `onResume` and as such they are both responding to item clicks when an item is pressed on either `Fragment`.

You could try moving the `onItemClickListener` to the `ViewHolder` in your `Adapter`, rather assigning it in `onResume`. In addition, I wonder what a `Brand` object looks like in your `RecyclerView`, and whether it wouldn't be simpler to pass the current `ViewPager` page as a parameter in `getInstance`, and use this to access an `Array` containing the information necessary to fill your `RecyclerView` rows.

Here is a very brief example of how your `ViewHolder` may look:

```
class MyRecyclerViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener

    public MyRecyclerViewHolder(View itemView) {
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);

        //etc.
```